# How to pass the values from the function fgetcsv() into view in codeigniter?

Tags: html, codeigniter-3, php-5.3, mpdf, fgetcsv

using mPDF library to create PDF. The file is created, I'm try to create different PDF files, but it creates the number of files I require, but all the files contain the same data of the first one. This is a sample code of my issue

**Controller**

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Home extends CI_Controller{

    public function page1(){
            $this->load->view('view_upload');

    }

        public function page2(){
       $file = fopen($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], 'r+');          
         $i=0;

           $user['data']=fgetcsv($file);
           echo "<br><br>";
           //print_r($user);

           //load the view and saved it into $html variable
             $html=$this->load->view('print_1', $user, true);

           //this the the PDF filename that user will get to download
            $pdfFilePath = $i.".pdf";

           //load mPDF library
            $this->load->library('m_pdf');

           //generate the PDF from the given html
            $this->m_pdf->pdf->WriteHTML($html);

           //download it.
            $this->m_pdf->pdf->Output("output/".$pdfFilePath, 'F');



           ++$i;
           $html=$this->load->view('print', $user, true);

           //this the the PDF filename that user will get to download
            $pdfFilePath = $i.".pdf";

           //load mPDF library
            $this->load->library('m_pdf');

           //generate the PDF from the given html
            $this->m_pdf->pdf->WriteHTML($html);

           //download it.
            $this->m_pdf->pdf->Output("output/".$pdfFilePath, 'F');

        fclose($file); 

}
}
```

**VIEWS ARE:**

*print_1*

```
<?php
echo "print_1";
?>
```

*print*

```
<?php
echo "print";
?>
```

It creates two PDF files, both have the data "**print_1**".
Remark: There is no use of the variable $user, it is used in my actual code

Comment: what's wrong with your code .and where your struggle ? And you can send multidimensional array in same way as in your post

Comment: What is output of `var_dump($data);`? Extend your question with that info.

Comment: What Actually you want. ? Could you please Explore.

Comment: @Tpojka var_dump($data) shows      array(1) { [0]=> array(19) { [0]=> string(1) "1" [1]=> string(11) "Dr.Jaya V L" [2]=> string(54) "Associate Professor in EC (NC), In Charge of Principal" [3]=> string(3) "183" [4]=> string(5) "28400" [5]=> string(5) "70148" [6]=> string(5) "98548" [7]=> string(3) "380" [8]=> string(0) "" [9]=> string(5) "98928" [10]=> string(0) "" [11]=> string(5) "11826" [12]=> string(0) "" [13]=> string(5) "10000" [14]=> string(0) "" [15]=> string(0) "" [16]=> string(0) "" [17]=> string(5) "21826" [18]=> string(5) "77102" } }

Comment: What is wrong? The code looks like it should output to your PDF view. My suggestion would be to turn off any PDF output headers and see if there is an error being generated. I expect the issue is your PDFs aren't being generated. Turn off the headers and see if PHP errors. (basically just output $html - exit and turn errors on)

Comment: in your sample output - you only have one line - is that the problem ?

Comment: It have so many lines, but the output shows only the first line. If I try to print that, it will show all the contents, but try to generate PDF, then it has the first line on all the files

Comment: I found that problem is in the third party library mPDF, it produce PDF files entire on the program of the initial input. Waiting for a help from mPDF....

Answer (score 0):

try this (is it really that obvious?)

in your print.php

```
foreach($data AS $key => $arrData)
{
    echo implode(",",$arrData);
    echo "<br />";
}
```

Comment: Same problem exist